# How do I deactivate At1lc driver after install of Alx driver? (replacement)

Tags: atheros, ethernet

I have had a problem with no wired Internet connection in 12.04 and my Atheros 8151 Ethernet card and I followed the procedure to replace the non-working driver (At1lc) with it's replacement the Alx.  The procedure seemed to work very well until I re-booted and the original (At1lc) driver still appeared in my lsw -c network.  The procedure I followed is described in

[How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-to-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

I repeated the procedure three times and each time the process and result were the same.
How do I deactivate the At1lc and activate the Alx?

Answer (score 1):

Put it on the modprobe blacklist.

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add a line like this

```
blacklist moduleName
```

in your case

```
blacklist atl1c
```

Comment: I blacklisted the driver and still got nothing.  Then, I noticed "Qualcomm Atheros Gigabit Ethernet Driver" appeared in "additional drivers" list of proprietary drivers.  It hadn't been there before.  It said that the driver was "activated but not currently in use."  I activated another driver (graphics) and restarted.  When I checked the system, ALX was functioning.  Now I don't have to rely on wireless. Thank you.