# Why does compiling the "alx" driver from "compat-wireless" fail?

Tags: networking, drivers

Trying to compile the compat-wireless-2012-09-25 driver module, without success.

scrips/driver-select alx  ; works

make ; fails -
scripts/Makefile.build:44 ~/sourcecode/compat-wireless-2012-09-25.2/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile: No such file or directory

make[4]: ** No rule to make target '~/sourcecode/compat-wireless-2012-09-25.2/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile'. Stop.

[snip]

make: *** [modules] Error 2

Device is Atheros AR8161 wired ethernet in a Dell Vostro 3460.

I'd be very grateful for assistance in getting this to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alx` drivers are a "patch" in *compat-wireless* instead of being in the main tree. This means that you need to download a `compat-wireless` archive **with the `-pc` suffix** to be able to build them.

Try http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-09-25-pc.tar.bz2 and it should work.

Comment: Paul: since the answer worked, please consider accepting it (check/tick mark on the left) so that it's marked as closed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the alx driver is available packaged now, so you may not need to install it from source. This will save you having to reinstall it each time the kernel version gets bumped.

try: `apt-cache search linux-backports-modules`

and then depending on your ubuntu version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
sudo modprobe alx
```

See: [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)