# Does Ubuntu 12.10 support ASIX AX88772 Ethernet controller chip out-of-the-box?

Tags: networking, drivers, 12.10, hardware, compatibility

Being stuck with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217361/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller-on-64-bit-12) I am choosing a USB Ethernet adapter to buy to work it around.

Obviously I need an adapter for which Ubuntu has drivers built-in.

So the question is if [AXAGO ADE-X5 USB](http://www.axago.cz/cz/produkty/usb-adaptery/ADE-X5.html) said to be based on [the ASIX AX88772 chip](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=86;71;101) is going to work. It is said to support Linux but that doesn't necessarily mean the driver is actually built in to the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver for this chip is in the Linux kernel module `asix`. This module will handle a lot of USB vendor/product combinations as of the version in Ubuntu's `3.5.0-18`:

```
$ modinfo asix
filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/asix.ko
license:        GPL
description:    ASIX AX8817X based USB 2.0 Ethernet Devices
version:        22-Dec-2011
author:         David Hollis
srcversion:     0889AC645D9EA92D3DE4C5B
alias:          usb:v0B95p7E2Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0DB0pA877d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*

<snip>

alias:          usb:v0846p1040d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v077Bp2226d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        usbnet
intree:         Y
```

However, I find [some (old) bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=587215) stating it won't work out of the box in Debian. And, more importantly, if you need this in a Live environment, make sure it is one with [one of these packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=asix.ko&mode=&suite=quantal&arch=any) installed into.

Comment: "This module will handle a lot of USB vendor/product combinations as of the version in Ubuntu's 3.5.0-18" - the kernel I've got is `3.5.0-17` (not `-18`). "you need a Live environment" - why? I've got the fully (but the NIC) functional Ubuntu installed on the hard drive.

Comment: @Ivan In that case, just install ``linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic``. The ``-18`` kernel I'm using is pre-release I guess.

Comment: I've just bought the NIC and tested it. It works just fine with bare 12.10 installation. The -18 kernel was installed as soon as I've ran update.