# BCM43142: No network devices detected

Tags: wireless, 12.10, dell, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell Vostro 3460 and no network devices are detected (ethernet and wireless).

when I run `lspci`, I see:

```
1:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 821.11b/g/n (rev 01)
2:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

`rfkill list all` lists only the Bluetooth device.

Ethernet works (with the help of [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller on 64-bit 12.10 using an Internet-connected 32-bit 12.04 PC and a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217361/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller-on-64-bit-12)).

The wireless driver is installed (following [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)), but it is not functioning.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do and which doesn't seem to have been suggested yet, is to open Additional Drivers (`jockey-gtk`), and check if you can install the proprietary drivers for your wireless card (if any). Then I would suggest a precautionary reboot.

If it still doesn't work, right-click NetworkManager and ensure that **Enable Wireless** is checked.

If it still doesn't work, then double-check wireless connectivity using `wicd-gtk` (`sudo apt-get install wicd`).

Answer (score 1):

These commands worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

I hope it gets you up and running. Have a great day, and good luck!

Here is a ref for the b43 official Ubuntu Community wiki: [Ubuntu B43 Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your laptop does not have a hardware button for turning off your wireless. you can also check in BIOS if it is disabled.

Otherwise, I sometimes have problems with networking in Ubuntu, and then I simply use the Debian ways, e.g. edit `/etc/networking/interfaces`

and use tools such as

```
ifup eth0
```

or

```
ifconfig
```

to set up and test network equipment.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try connecting using manual method:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

to scan for any AP

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "ssid"
sudo iwconfig wlan0 key "password"
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

to configure the network / obtaining ip address