# Couldn't connect using a wired Atheros AR8161 NIC

Tags: connection, wired

This is my first time using ubuntu. I am using verion 12.04 and I can't connect through wired connection.

The network card I am using is Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08).

The logical name of this network is eth2. Is there a wrong configuration in my system?

I am using a home router, which is dynamic connection (the router has DHCP server running).

My `ifconfig` is:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:18:85:d2:c9:a3  
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c218:85ff:fed2:c9a3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17133 errors:17 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:247488
          TX packets:10304 errors:7 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22986154 (22.9 MB)  TX bytes:1059388 (1.0 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:0e:a1:ef:4f:79  
          inet6 addr: fe80::de0e:a1ff:feef:4f79/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:48578 (48.5 KB)  TX bytes:104673 (104.6 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:126065 (126.0 KB)  TX bytes:126065 (126.0 KB)
```

I tried to disable my IPV6 also the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Please specify, what problems you are facing?

Comment: I just plugin cable to my laptop. The system say that it is connecting. Then after a while it stop trying to connect to the network

Comment: Is your connection statc or dynamic?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `ifconfig`. Does your system also have a wireless adapter? Problem similar to [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/288744/cant-connect-to-ethernet-with-atheros-ar8161-on-ubuntu-12-04-2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

Answer (score 0):

The AR8161 cards seem to have driver support issues under most flavors of UNIX which result in the card showing up in `ifconfig` but not properly functioning. (Google searching the card name will yield a lot of "not functioning" post results.) Answers in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217361/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller-on-64-bit-12) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller) detail how to install the kernel support needed for the Atheros card.