# Lenovo Y580 reinstall network drivers

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, lenovo

I had some issues with WiFi with my Lenovo y580, I could connect my home WiFi but it would disonnect me after few minutes and I wasn't able to reconnect
I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I believe my network card is "AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet"

Changes I have been doing before it stopped working at all:

```
191  lspci -vv | grep Atheros
192  sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
193  wget -O- http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2 | tar -xj
194  cd compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc
195  ./scripts/driver-select alx
196  make
197  sudo make install
198  sudo modprobe alx
```

It would be great if I could revert this change so ubuntu would use the previous standard driver.
Then I could at least connect to some WiFi and maybe this problem was router's issue and not my network driver one

Thanks for any help

Comment: The device and driver you show are for ehternet not wifi. Please run `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod` post the output at http://pastebin.com/ then post the link here. Thanks

Comment: @WildMan http://pastebin.com/5vCeNPAd
By reinstalling packages listed in following question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217361/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller-on-64-bit-12
I am now back in state where I aws before
-home WiFi works for a few minutes, but then disconnects and not even restarting the router does help then...
However I have no connection problems with connecting via mobilephone wifi hotspot, however I have 2GB bandwidth limit on mobile and it is rather limiting

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after going 4 hours without being disconnected I can say, that I have solved the issue

The solution is to go to Network -> Edit Connections -> Wireless -> Click on WiFi -> Edit -> IPv6 Settings

There, you have to select Method: Ignore

So it is IPv6 related issue. Somehow.