# If the net is required to install an Atheros 8161 driver,how do I connect to the net without the driver?

Tags: networking

If Ubuntu does not recognize hardware to connect to the net, and a net connection is necessary in order to install drivers for hardware that connects to the net, then how is such a system ever going to connect to the net?

You can see the situation in this thread:

[How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

and in this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/217860/build-essential-and-linux-headers-generic-gives-abort-message

Surely, surely, there is a way out of this catch-22.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

You can download linux-headers-generic and build-essential *and all their dependencies* on another computer and transfer them on a USB key, CD or similar. Here is a forum post that describes the process. Caution: the driver *alx* described there may or may not be correct for your Atheros AR8161.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12206899&postcount=6