# What package should I install for driver of the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet Controller without net?

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, atheros

I've read in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller) Question that a new package exists for this driver. But I am confused. There are a lot of [packages](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-backports-modules-3.5.0/) and I don't know which one do I need. 
I have a DellVostro-3460, Ubuntu 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

Answer (score 1):

For 12.10, you need linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic. You will also need its dependency linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-17.

Comment: It doesn't work! So sorry!
I can find linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-17-generic_3.5.0-17.1_amd64.deb and linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic_3.5.0.22.28_amd64.deb only but it needs linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-22 and doesn't fit to my kernel version. I can not find the same version of them. I have no network conection and cannot mount usb, I copy files by CD-RW. I hadn't been got such problems since years!