# How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller? - update

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I checked [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

I have same problem:
when I pasted this part

```
wget -O- http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2 | tar -xj
```

I got the error:

```
--2013-01-29 20:13:55--  http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2
Resolving linuxwireless.org (linuxwireless.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `linuxwireless.org'

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

 It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
 You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.
 You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
 data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Please try this instead: http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit the following has worked for me:

Download and extract [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2).

```
cd compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/  
./scripts/driver-select alx  
make  
sudo make install  
sudo modprobe alx #Loads the module (or restart)
```