# Ubuntu 12.04 Installer Can't Detect My On-Board Network Interface

Tags: 12.04, installation, networking

Currently installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 Server and I get an error saying it can't detect my network interface device.

My board is Gigabyte Z77MX-D3H-TH.

The installer allows me to continue though. Is there a way to resolve this later on? I tried googling the issue but couldn't find anything substantial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that might just help you out right here on askubuntu!
[How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link as I found out that I had exactly the AR8161 controller. However, I'm still a noob about this whole installation thing and I can't figure out one thing about the instructions there - how do I do apt-get when my network card isn't configured? No internet!

My guess is to do this from another machine. But how do I transfer the files to this one then? Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: I did some more digging and found this: http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx. I downloaded the tarball, then copied it to a USB, then followed the instructions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) to manually mount the USB. However, I couldn't get it to mount after the "sudo mount -t vfat..." command. I got an error saying FAT-fs (sdc): invalid media value (0xb9). wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc...Doing fdisk -l returns W95 FAT32 (LBA) as the file system.

Comment: After reading through some links...I tried mounting sdc1 instead of just sdc and the thing mounted...hoo boy :)

Now to try untarballing...

Comment: Ok, I got as far as executing the "make" command. Then I got "The program 'make' is currently not installed. You can install it by sudo apt-get install make." I'm nearing the end of my patience with this. Why wouldn't make be installed by default?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to detect the network card from BIOS or by booting via latest ubuntu desktop CD or from a windows boot.

Then try googling for the tar bundle or OEM provided network driver and compile them and check if this work.

See  also if the command

```
lshw -C network
```

from command line gives more details on the network card.

Comment: Thanks. I found out from this that I indeed had the Atheros AR8161 controller. And Scott provided the link which had a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to get around this problem. I plugged in an extra LAN card I had lying around, the installer detected it, then I followed the instructions in Scott's link and apt-get installed the additional module for the controller.