# How do I enable the alx ethernet driver on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 13.04, atheros

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit on my Lenovo IdeaPad laptop and am having trouble getting the Ethernet to work.

The `alx` driver required for my laptop's AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet controller to work have not been included in previous versions of Ubuntu, so I used to install the the driver using the `compat-wireless-pc` driver package.

Now Ubuntu 13.04 comes with the `alx` driver, however it does not appear to be functional. When I plug in an Ethernet cable, it is not detected. I have verified the `alx` module exists

```
$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/ubuntu/alx/alx.ko
version:        1.2.3
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros Gigabit Ethernet Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
srcversion:     DEB551A4F9D0281F98F5F10
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.8.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

and is loaded.

```
$ lsmod | grep alx
alx                    67960  0 
mdio                   13807  1 alx
```

Any suggestions on how to get my Ethernet up and running?

Comment: Are there any informative messages here? dmesg | grep -e alx -e eth0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same network card on my machine, and was also left without a working internet connection. I was able to get it up and running by downloading the source code for the driver (from [its homepage at the Linux Foundation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx)) and compiling it:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
```

After I loaded the new module (`sudo modprobe -r alx && sudo modprobe alx`) Connection Manager automatically re-connected.