# Ethernet port won't stay turned on

Tags: 12.04, networking, xubuntu, ethernet

When I originally got internet service my ethernet port was not turned on. Found this thread [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller), followed directions under answer 1 and it enabled my ethernet port. Now, the problem is that every time I disconnect the ethernet cable or restart my computer, I have to go through the process all over again to enable my ethernet port. How do I make this change permanent so that my ethernet port remains on? I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: Is it the `modprobe ...` command that you have to run?

Comment: I have to run all of the commands in order to get it to function each time.

Comment: You mean you have to reinstall it every time? :-s

Comment: Seems to be the case. Just running 'sudo modprobe alx' alone doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you referring to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/210466/178596) - once it is installed, it should stay installed. Also, please add the output of `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-precise-generic` command.

Comment: I'm referring to the answer where you have to build and install the driver by downloading the compat-wireless-pc driver package.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12286/discussion-between-jason-smith-and-wilf)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo alx | sudo tee /etc/modules
```

This will add the module to the [`/etc/modules`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/modules.5.html) file, so it loads automatically, and so you don't have to run the `sudo modprobe alx` command every time.

Comment: I got the following error when running this command and tried running it with sudo and got the same error message: bash: /etc/modules: Permission denied

Comment: Whooops... changed answer ;-)